# PHPMailer : SMTP host connection error on Godaddy

Tags: php

> Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.;

this error is generating when i run this code in godaddy.

```
<?php
require("PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtpout.secureserver.net"; // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "username@domain.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "******"; // SMTP password
$mail->From     = "username@domain.com";
$mail->FromName = "User";
$mail->AddAddress("Sendto@gmail.com"); // name is optional
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true); // set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";
if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
}
echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Comment: I believe you have to contact the godaddy support.

Comment: Maybe godaddy is blocking outgoing traffic on tcp/25 port (SMTP).

Comment: Where is $mail->Port ?  

Outgoing Port
Without SSL - one of the following: 25, 80, 3535, 587 
With SSL - 465

Answer (score 2):

Try below code it's working for me!

```
<?php
require("src/PHPMailer.php");
require("src/SMTP.php");
require("src/Exception.php");

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->Port = 25;

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('from@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('to@gmail.com', 'XYZTABC');
//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($e);
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: The SMTPDebug line caused an error for me, but other than that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, using the SMTP address you are using you need to specify the port too (465).

However, according to the godaddy documentation, you should be using the following SMTP server:

```
relay-hosting.secureserver.net
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you.

```
$mail->Host     = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
```

your host name should be like `mydomain.com`

```
$mail->Port = 465;
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this using localhost as smtp server, port 25,  no ssl and no  authentication.
I'm using wordpress, with divi theme on a godaddy server.